# Is it possible to wrap ReactJs webApps so as to build a crossplatform mobileApp?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, web-applications

I was wondering if it is possible to wrap a reactjs web app with some kind of browser in order to create apps for iOS and Android...

If so, does it have some disadvantages other than performance and resource access? E.g: can’t fully control the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible, but you can build mobile apps using react-native, or react-native Expo for cross platform development for iOS and android.

Here's [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v34.0.0/)